# Spark Streaming tuning number of records per batch size not working?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, dstream

My spark streaming app is reading from kafka using DStream approach and I'm trying to get the batch size to process 60,000 messages in 10 seconds.

What I've done,

- Created a topic with 3 partitions
- `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition = 60000`
- `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled = true`
- set my batch duration to 10 seconds when I create the
  StreamingContext
- running in yarn mode with 2 executors (4 cores total for 3
  partitions)

Now how I test that this is working.

I have a producer that sends 60,000 messages at once to the topic. When I check the spark UI I get the following:

```
 batch time | Input size | processing time
 10:54:30   | 17610      | 5s
 10:54:20   | 32790      | 8s
 10:54:10   | 9600       | 3s
```

So each batch time is 10 s apart. What I expect is 1 batch with 60,000 records. Is there some other parameter I am not setting? From what I have read about what I've currently set I should be getting 10 * 60,000 * 3  = 1800000 in a single batch.

```
spark.app.id  = application_1551747423133_0677

spark.app.name = KafkaCallDEV

spark.driver.cores = 2

spark.driver.extraJavaOptions   = -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties -verbose:gc

spark.driver.memory = 3g

spark.driver.port   = 33917

spark.executor.cores = 2

spark.executor.extraJavaOptions = -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties -verbose:gc

spark.executor.id   = driver

spark.executor.instances    = 2

spark.executor.memory   = 2g

spark.master    = yarn

spark.scheduler.mode    = FIFO

spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled    = true

spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition = 60000

spark.submit.deployMode = cluster

spark.ui.filters    = org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter

spark.ui.port = 0

spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir = /data0/yarn/container-logs/application_1551747423133_0677/container_1551747423133_0677_01_000002
```

Below is what I printed out using

```
logger.info(sparkSession.sparkContext.getConf.getAll.mkString("\n"))
```

I removed some of the unnecessary logs like server address, app name, etc..

```
(spark.executor.extraJavaOptions,-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:ConcGCThreads=2

-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties -verbose:gc) (spark.yarn.app.id,application_1551747423133_0681)

(spark.submit.deployMode,cluster)

(spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled,true)

(spark.yarn.credentials.renewalTime,1562764821939ms)

(spark.ui.filters,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter)

(spark.executor.memory,2g) 

(spark.yarn.credentials.updateTime,1562769141873ms)

(spark.driver.cores,2) 

(spark.executor.id,driver)

(spark.executor.cores,2)

(spark.master,yarn)

(spark.driver.memory,3g)

(spark.sql.warehouse.dir,/user/hive/warehouse) 

(spark.ui.port,0)

(spark.driver.extraJavaOptions,-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:ConcGCThreads=2
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties -verbose:gc) 

(spark.executor.instances,2)

(spark.driver.port,37375)
```

I've also got some Kafka config's that are being printed so I will post those below too.

```
    org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig:178 - ConsumerConfig values: 
        metric.reporters = []
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        enable.auto.commit = false
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        interceptor.classes = null
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        client.id = 
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        max.poll.records = 60000
        check.crcs = true
        request.timeout.ms = 40000
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.key.password = null
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        session.timeout.ms = 30000
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition = 60000
means that

> the maximum rate (in messages per second) at which each Kafka
>   partition will be read by this direct API which will be enabled by property `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled = true`

***17610 + 32790 + 9600  = 60000*** your batch size is achieved.

---

see [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/enable-back-pressure-make-your-spark-streaming-production-lan-jiang/) 
[image]

your 3 kafka partitions (having 60k messaages) is read by spark in chunks/spark  partitions, in your case, 3 partitions from spark.   but original number of messages in 3 kafka partitions are 60000 (17610 + 32790 + 9600). Even high message rate input flow is coming back pressure will maintain the uniform rate of messages using [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) and [PIDRateEstimator](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/rate/PIDRateEstimator.scala)

So you are done here....

Further reffer my [post -*Short note on Spark Streaming Back Pressure* for better understanding](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/short-note-spark-streaming-backpressure-ram-ghadiyaram/)

***Conclusion : 
If you enable back pressure, Irrespective of what rate you are sending the messages. it will allow constant rate of messages***

like this illustratative geneal example ... where back pressure properties are like inflow control - pressure adjusting screw to maintain uniform rate of message flow.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ram. My topic has 3 partitions. I send 60K messages at once to this topic. I have shown you some of the stats in my original post. It takes 3 batches of 10 s each to process all 60K messages, with each batch taking variable amounts of data.

Comment: logger.info(sparkContext.getConf.getAll.mkString("\n")) just print these and post pls !

Comment: Hi Ram I've posted config info

Answer (score 0):

So I found the reason why Spark is breaking up the batch of records that I send into multiple batches. I have `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled = true`. This uses a feedback loop from previous batches to control the receiving rate which is upper bounded by the max rate per partition which I set in `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition`. So spark is tuning the receiving rate for me.

Comment: " spark is tuning the receiving rate for me  " this is what i was telling in my first line of answer. see [my post here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/short-note-spark-streaming-backpressure-ram-ghadiyaram/)

Comment: "this is what I was telling in my first line of answer" - I actually posted my answer above regarding backpressure info and you mentioned it in your post in an edit the day after I posted.